# Photon, How to get player variable

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, photon

I'm putting Photon into my project but I would like to find out if a player is ready with customplayerproperties.

I've been able to set them using:

```
    Hashtable hash = new Hashtable();
    hash.Add("ready", false);
    PhotonNetwork.LocalPlayer.SetCustomProperties(hash);
```

But then I have no idea how to get that information back again from all players.

I have tried this method:

```
public override void OnPlayerPropertiesUpdate(Player target, ExitGames.Client.Photon.Hashtable changedProps)
{
    base.OnPlayerPropertiesUpdate(target, changedProps);
    
    if (!PhotonNetwork.IsMasterClient) 
        return;
    if (!changedProps.ContainsKey("ready"))
        return;
}
```

But when compiled into Unity I get the error:

```
The type or namespace name 'Player' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

And I get another error for that override being:

```
'PlayerReadied.OnPlayerPropertiesUpdate(Player, Hashtable)': no suitable method found to override
```

I don't know what to do here, if anyone could help that would be great!!

I really appreciate any help you can provide.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check your 'using' statements in that file, it should have these I think:

```
using Photon.Pun;
using Photon.Realtime;
```

Maybe related, if you are upgrading from Photon Unity Networking 1 to 2, there were namespace changes that might give you those issues: https://doc.photonengine.com/en-us/pun/current/getting-started/migration-notes

*Edit* Do you have a 'Player' class in your program as well? I think your 'Player' class is being used in that method signature instead of PUN's one.

Comment: Thank you very much! I knew I was missing something simple but I couldn't find it out. I had Photon.Pun, but not Realtime. This fixed my problem!